# How to do Automatic Entry Of Recurring Amounts Using Triggers In SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite, triggers

A tricky question around using triggers in SQLite to do auto updates...

I have a situation here where I need to make entries in a table at certain intervals starting on a specifc date. Each category in the "**Category**" table has a "**RecurAmount**" that is set to recur at one of 4 fixed intervals: 7days, 14 days, 1 month, 1 year. ( I represent these by the integers 1,2,3,4) Each category has a **RecurDate** which is initially chosen by the user. Once this date passes I need to have the Application do the following ( assume for example the application hasnt been opened for a couple of months and  needs to be refreshed):

1) Select all categories from **Category** where the **RecurDate** is <= date('now') ... These are categories due to be refreshed.

2) Insert into "**Costs**" table **RecurAmount** ,**RecurDate**, **CatKey**, **Recur** values taken from the "**Categories**" table into the following **Costs** columns:  **Amount**, **CostDate**,**CatFK**, **AutoExp**

3) I need to then be able to have SQLite insert the amount at regular interval dates into the **Costs** table automatically at the interval determined by the "**Recur**" value. So if its **Recur** value is "1" I need a sequence of entries made into the **Costs** table at 7 day intervals starting on the **RecurDate** and going as far as todays date but no further.

4) Once all categories have had their recurring cost enties applied up to the current date...I need one future date to be added into the **RecurDate** field back in the **Category** table. This will serve as the next date which needs to be matched or passsed before the next auto entry occurs.

Here are the tables Im working with:
"**Category**" table:

```
RecurDate       Key      RecurAmount    Recur   RecurInterval
2012-06-26      20       100            1            Weekly
2012-07-18       21        200          1            Weekly
2012-07-10       22        250          3            Monthly
2012-08-10       22        300          3            Monthly
2012-07-16       23        200          2            Fortnightly
2012-06-20       24       100           4             Yearly
```

"**Costs**" table.  This is the table that receives the inserted amounts  at regular date intervals.
Assuming todays date is 2012-07-18 when I start up the app after a long period without doing so... I need the Costs table to update to something like this:

```
CostDate    CatFK       Amount      AutoExp

2012-06-26    20          100       1       
2012-07-03    20          100       1
2012-07-10    20          100       1
2012-07-17    20          100       1
2012-07-18    21          200       1
2012-07-10    22          250       3
2012-07-16    23          200       2
2012-06-20    24          100       4
```

Here is the start of my code so far which attempts to just accomplish the weekly recurring expenses. It's not working obviously...

```
PRAGMA recursive_triggers = on
CREATE TEMPORARY TRIGGER MyTrigger
BEFORE INSERT ON Costs
WHEN new.RecurDate < (select date('now','localtime')) BEGIN
INSERT INTO Costs (CostDate, Amount, CatFK, AutoExp)
VALUES (date(new.RecurDate,'+'||7||' days'), Category.RecurAmount, Category.Key,    Category.Recur;
END

INSERT INTO Costs (CostDate, Amount, CatFK, AutoExp)
SELECT RecurDate, RecurAmount,Key, Recur from Category
WHERE
Recur =1 ;
```

As you can see I'm heading down the path of using triggers somehow to accomplish this, but I'm a long way off getting this done. The complexity comes from the varying recurring intervals I'm dealing with and identifying and inserting the future "RecurDate" back into the Categories table based on these different intervals. I'm almost thinking I construct a custom statement outside SQLIte using AS3 and a loop to workout the dates, then INsert back in what I need into SQLite.

I'm wondering if someone could please give me some pointers because this is pretty tricky and I'm not very good :)

Thanks

Marco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the main problem is how to generate the necessary CostDate values given the RecurDate value of each row, between CostDate and today's date.

I don't know anything about SQLlite but I could solve the problem in SQL server, so I'll try to explain the logic required.

I'd suggest doing this in 4 passes, once for each of the refresh cycles. So I'll assume in the narrative following, that we are creating the new rows where the recurring period is each 7 days. You should be able to duplicate the logic for the other cycles as required.

You'll need a temporary table of integer values (numbers of days) starting from 0 (=earliest RecurDate) upto and including today. So for example if the earliest date is 142 days ago, the table will need to contain the values 0 through 142; Alternatively, if we can assume that the earliest possible RecurDate is 1000 days ago or less (ie close to 3 years ago), we can say the table will ALWAYS need to contain the values 0 to 1000.

To create this, well I'm not sure what syntax you'll need, but I would do this:

```
    create table Days (interval int);
    insert Days values (0);
    insert Days values (1);

    declare @offset int, @max int;
    select @offset = 2, @max = 1000  /*(1000 per the assumption of a maximum value)*/
    while @offset < @max begin
      insert Days 
      select interval + @offset 
      from Days 
      where interval + @offset <= @max
    end
```

The data in this table needs to be cross-joined (ie creating a caretesian product, where all rows in the first table match all rows in the other table) with the categories in the insert statement creating the new rows:

```
    insert costs (Amount, CostDate, CatFK, AutoExp)
    select c.RecurAmount, c.RecurDate + d.interval, c.Catkey, c.Recur
    from Categories c cross join Days d
    where c.RecurDate < getdate()      /*'now'*/
      and c.Recur = 1
      and c.RecurDate + d.interval <= getdate()
      and d.interval > 0
      and d.interval mod 7 = 0;
```

Thus we insert into the costs table, the categories table columns + periods, for all categories where the RecurDate is before today's date, and the recur interval is 1 (weekly), and RecurDate + the period in use is less than or equal to today's date,
and the period isnt 0 (so you don't create a record dated = RecurDate) and the period used for each insert is evenly divisible by 7.

I've assumed (or I read it wrong) that after this process runs, the RecurDate will be updated per the most recent CostDate in costs for each Category.

Hope this helps :-) JB

Comment: Hi John

Thanks for your detailed response, it seems like an interesting method to try that doesn't seem too complicated. I'll see if I can get this to work in SQLite.

Comment: I got this to work with a couple of tweaks for SQLite:  I changed getdate() to julianday('now','localtime')   and d.interval>0 to d.interval >= 0 in order to get the first date entered as well. Thanks for your help John.   M